# How to remove Accounts bundle from OroCRM

Tags: bundle, account, orocrm

What is the procedure for removing the Accounts bundle from OroCRM?

The accounts feature does not fit into our use case and we prefer to use contacts without having to manage account.

Thanks in advance!

Have tried removing the bundle via Composer and manually without success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.